# ¿Como detectar cuando se cierra un proceso usando C#?

Tags: c#, proceso

Estoy desarrollando un programa usando C# y entre las cosas que hace, debe lanzar un Programa.exe y luego detectar cuando este se cierra para cerrar Mi_Programa.exe.
Eh intentado usar:

```
static void taka()
        {            
            bool started = false;
            var p = new Process();
            var prevID = 0;

            if (gameStarted == false)
            {
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "programa.exe";
                started = p.Start();                
                prevID = p.Id;
                Console.WriteLine($prevID {prevID});                
                gameStarted = true;
            }            

            if (gameStarted == true)
            {
                bool check = false;

                try
                {
                    var procId = p.Id;
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(ID  + procId);
                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                    
                    // Recorremos los procesos en ejecución
                    foreach (Process Proc in processes)
                    {
                        if (Proc.Id == p.Id)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ProcID =  + Proc.Id);
                            Console.WriteLine(New_PID =  + p.Id);
                            gameStillRunning = true;
                            check = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    started = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    started = false;
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                if (check == false)
                    gameStillRunning = false;
            }
        }
```

Esto de momento detecta el proceso y su PID, pero al estar dentro de un loop, la segunda vez que se ejecuta salta el error "Invalid operation exeption", sin embargo sigue mostrando los PID.
Tal vez este metodo no sea el indicado para realizar esta tarea asi que estoy abierto a la idea de cambiar por completo el metodo.

NOTA: Anteriormente intente usar metodo booleano para que me retorne un valor, pero luego de varios intentos fallidos, gracias al error "Invalid operation exeption" no me retornaba los valores correcto asi que, casi en contra de mi voluntad, opte por usar variables globales para intentar resolver esto.

NOTA2: bool started, ya estaba en uno de los ejemplos que copie asi que la deje ahi pero no tiene ninguna funcion real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento [**Process.Exited**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Si revisas el ejemplo de la documentación puedes crear un EventHandler

```
...
... 
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.Start();
```

el cual será llamado cuando tu proceso termine.

```
// Maneja el evento Exited y muestra la información del proceso.
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Exit time    : {myProcess.ExitTime}\n" +
        $"Exit code    : {myProcess.ExitCode}\n" +
        $"Elapsed time : {Math.Round((myProcess.ExitTime - myProcess.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds)}");
    eventHandled.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

---

Ejemplo completo de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class PrintProcessClass
{
    private Process myProcess;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> eventHandled;

    // Print a file with any known extension.
    public async Task PrintDoc(string fileName)
    {
        eventHandled = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        using (myProcess = new Process())
        {
            try
            {
                // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
                myProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred trying to print \"{fileName}\":\n{ex.Message}");
                return;
            }

            // Wait for Exited event, but not more than 30 seconds.
            await Task.WhenAny(eventHandled.Task,Task.Delay(30000));
        }
    }

    // Handle Exited event and display process information.
    private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Exit time    : {myProcess.ExitTime}\n" +
            $"Exit code    : {myProcess.ExitCode}\n" +
            $"Elapsed time : {Math.Round((myProcess.ExitTime - myProcess.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds)}");
        eventHandled.TrySetResult(true);
    }

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Verify that an argument has been entered.
        if (args.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name.");
            return;
        }

        // Create the process and print the document.
        PrintProcessClass myPrintProcess = new PrintProcessClass();
        await myPrintProcess.PrintDoc(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me ayudo a resolver el problema!

Comment: Excelente @IgnacioBrocca , saludos!